# RxJava - Pass variable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code which compiles fine:

```
public Publisher<Foo> test() {
  return someObservable
         .map(a -> someMethod(a, null))
         .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

I would now like to call a method and pass in the results of it to use instead of the null value.  My guess is to wrap the original code like so:

```
public Publisher<Foo> test() {
  return getSomeCollection()
         .map(myCollection -> 
           someObservable
           .map(a -> someMethod(a, myCollection))
         )
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

However that gives me a type mismatch error `'Cannot convert from Single<Object> to Publisher<Foo>'`

If I change the outer map to flatMap I get `'Cannot convert from Flowable<Foo> to SingleSource<? extends Object>'`

What do I need to modify to make this compile?

Comment: What does `someMethod(a, myCollection)` return?

Comment: It returns Foo.

Comment: And what does `getSomeCollection()` return?

Comment: It shouldn't matter for this question, as it's just a way to pass through a variable. But, a Single<Collection<SomeObj>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatMapPublisher` instead of `map`

```
return getSomeCollection()
            .flatMapPublisher(myCollection ->
                    someObservable
                            .map(a -> someMethod(a, myCollection))
                            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            );
```